# Do I need Google App Engine to make and run a Facebook App?

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I set up the Google App Engine on my computer to work with Python , so I could make my first "Hello World"  App at http://localhost:8080/. In the developers section of facebook it says I need  Google App Engine and Python to test an app. But my question is, can I just host the files(the .yaml and the .py) on my server account instead(once I'm done testing)?

Comment: where does it say that? can i have a link please?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not specifically need Google app engine, that i believe is just a sample app. The main thing that you need is a globally accessible web server. So that FB can reach your pages/application from their servers. So depending on the language, get a small/free hosting account and test your application from there. Or you may also try Dynamic DNS to be able to reach your local machine from the outside world http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

Answer (score 3):

That example is written in Python and specifically targeted for Google App Engine. So, yes you do need Google App Engine to run that example without modification. However, almost any web hosting would suffice in general with your own application.